# Magento2 exclude orphan products from sitemap

Tags: magento2, sitemaps

Is there a way to exclude orphan products from a sitemap?

we have multiple storeviews in 1 store. We want the functionality that the customer can choose a product in one storeview and buy it in another storeview. For that to be possible we need to enable all products for all storeviews. 
BUT we dont want all products in all sitemaps for each store. That's why we are looking for a way to exclude products that are not in an active category for each storeview.

Comment: ` exclude products that are not in an active category for each storeview.` is not feasible  bcoz if a  product will assign at multiple categories then you facing some logic issue.For this requirement, you have to create an attribute which store each store code and then filter your sitemap product collection that attribute value

Comment: i dont really see why its not feasible. But i  think i will create my own product collection based on the active categorie in the chosen storeview. I thought there might be something i overlooked but probably not.